# declare variable while the variable name is a string?

Tags: javascript

everyone!

I have an array containing some strings:

```
strs = ['a1','a2','a3']
```

and an object is defined:

```
o={}
```

I wanna add properties to ***o*** while the property name is the string in array ***strs***
Any suggestion is appreciated

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try the following

```
for (var i = 0; i < strs.length; i++) {
  var name = strs[i];
  o[name] = i;
}
```

This code will create the properties with the given `name` on the object `o`.  After the loop runs you will be able to access them like so

```
var sum = o.a1 + o.a2 + o.a3;  // sum = 3
```

Here's a fiddle which has some sample code

- http://jsfiddle.net/eYJrJ/

Answer (score 1):

This can be done using **Square Bracket Notation**.

```
var strs = ['a1','a2','a3'];
var o = {};

for(i = 0; i<strs.length; i++)
{
    o[strs[i]] = "value";
}

document.write(o.a1);
```